# Python PDF script to merge PDF by filenames found in list variable

Tags: python

I have a script below that I'd like to read the variable `dwg_list` as the list to take PDF file names from for the `merger.append(pdf).

Basically it takes a list of pdf file names, uses that list to merge each individual file into one.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_excel('master.xlsx')
dwg_list = df['drawings'].tolist()
print(dwg_list)

pdfs = dwg_list  # how can I make this work?
merger = PdfFileMerger()

for pdf in pdfs:
    merger.append(pdf)

merger.write("Test.pdf")
merger.close()
```

Comment: what is not working? it seems ok, see [doc](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/merging-pdfs.html)

Comment: I believe it's looking for just the filename that was appended in the `dwg_list`. So if the list has `File1` `File2` `File3` it isn't including the ".pdf". How can I get it to look at file extension?

Comment: a basic approach to check extension would be: `if pdf.endswith('pdf'):`. Otherwise have a look to `os.path`, `pathlib` in the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/)

Comment: @cards Ah, for a bit more clarity - `merge_pdf(dwg_list)` is looking at the list of elements, which is `File1`, `File2` etc. So it's trying to look for a PDF named "File1" when in reality it's "File1.pdf". Does that make sense? I can't figure it out with my limited understanding.

Comment: No idea of what are talking about, sorry. Instead you could try to copy-paste **manually** a list of such pdfs `dwg_list = [File1 or what ever]` and check if it works

Comment: I don't understand your issue. Add the output of `print(dwg_list)` (in your question not as a comment)

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out and have a working program:

included `dwg_list = ([f'{i}.pdf' for i in dwg_list])` before `print(dwg_list).